# Error with passing array to a function (Lua)

Tags: arrays, lua

I get this error: attempt to index field 'array' (a nil value), this is my code:

```
aUItems = {}    
    aUItems[1] = tonumber(result[1].item_1)
    aUItems[2] = tonumber(result[1].item_2)
    aUItems[3] = tonumber(result[1].item_3)
    aUItems[4] = tonumber(result[1].item_4)
    aUItems[5] = tonumber(result[1].item_5)
    aUItems[6] = tonumber(result[1].item_6) -- Everything here is right, I checked it!
Network:Send(player, "UpdateAmount", aUItems ) -- Basicly calls the function

--function
function GK7Inv:UpdateAmount( array )
aItemsa[1] = array[1]
aItemsa[2] = array[2]
aItemsa[3] = array[3]
aItemsa[4] = array[4]
aItemsa[5] = array[5]
aItemsa[6] = array[6]
end
```

Comment: Are you expecting `Network:Send` to pass along `aUIItems` into `GK7Inv:UpdateAmount`? It doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It is. When I pass something like a number instead of aUItems (ofc i change the function in this case) it works fine.

Comment: @user3112337 Can you post the code for Network:Send?

Comment: maybe u should post the code when u call the function `UpdateAmount()`.

Comment: Network:Send definitly works (it's the code from a server software) and I call update amount right up their with Network:Send. You need to know that everything above --function is serverside and everything under is clientside. Network:Send just communicate from server -> client

Comment: So if you define `function GK7Inv:UpdateAmount( array ) print(type(array), array) end` and you do `Network:Send(player, "UpdateAmount", 123)` it prints "number 123" whereas if you do `Network:Send(player, "UpdateAmount", {})` you it prints "nil nil"?

Comment: How does `Send` know about `GK7Inv`? More specifically, how is `UpdateAmount` being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is how you are calling the function, which we don't see yet...

When you *define a function as a method* (by using `:` instead of `.`), it has an implicit first parameter named `self`. When you call it, you have to pass in the value for `self`, which is almost always done implicitly by *calling it as a method*. If you don't then your formal parameters will not be lined up with your actual parameters. Lua allows function calls to pass any number of parameters, without regard to the number of formal parameters. The default value is `nil`.

So, be sure to call a method like this:

```
GK7Inv:UpdateAmount(aUItems)
-- formal parameter self has the same value as GK7Inv
-- formal parameter array has the same value as aUItems
```

and not like this:

```
GK7Inv.UpdateAmount(aUItems)
-- formal parameter self has the same value as aUItems
-- formal parameter array has the default value nil
```

Of course, you don't have to define the function as a method, in which case, you would define it and call it using `.`

```
function GK7Inv.UpdateAmount( array )
-- ...
end
```

or, as an anonymous function, possibly stored in a variable rather than a table

```
(function ( array ) -- don't store the function value, just it as an expression called as a function
-- ...
end)(aUItems)

function UpdateAmount( array ) -- store the function value in a global variable
-- ...
end
UpdateAmount(aUItems)

local function UpdateAmount( array ) -- store the function value in a local variable
-- ...
end
UpdateAmount(aUItems)
```